# Replace character and previous character in Python

Tags: python-3.x

I need to replace each "්" and the previous character to it from the following paragraph. How can do that with Python 3?

> paalau jaiwaiThe thanaiya makana්nata dawasaka්‌ oba mata hamauwauwaa
>   andaurau maawaThe atha්waela්‌ baendagarena apa daredarenaa paiyamna්‌
>   karerauwaa kaisaidaa nomaekarena mathake raendailaa oba maa haeradaa
>   warena්wauwaa obatama urauma magema saihainaya obage ahase laiyawewaa

Comment: SO is generally accepted as an English-language site. Since you did the title in English, it should hopefully be a short step toward doing the body as well. Otherwise, let us know and we'll try to google-translate it for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're looking for [**`re.sub()`**](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/re.html#re.sub):

```
import re
result = re.sub(".?්", "[REPLACE WITH]", "paalau jaiwaiThe thanaiya makana්nata dawasaka්‌ oba mata hamauwauwaa andaurau maawaThe atha්waela්‌ baendagarena apa daredarenaa paiyamna්‌ karerauwaa kaisaidaa nomaekarena mathake raendailaa oba maa haeradaa warena්wauwaa obatama urauma magema saihainaya obage ahase laiyawewaa")
print(result)
```

---

### Explanation

- The first argument is a [**regex**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) that matches `්`, any single character that precedes it (`.`), if there is one (`?`).
- The second argument is the text you want to replace these characters with.
- The third and last argument is your source string.

Comment: This worked
result = re.sub(".?්", "[REPLACE WITH]", "paalau jaiwaiThe thanaiya makana්nata dawasaka්‌ oba mata hamauwauwaa andaurau maawaThe atha්waela්‌ baendagarena apa daredarenaa paiyamna්‌ karerauwaa kaisaidaa nomaekarena mathake raendailaa oba maa haeradaa warena්wauwaa obatama urauma magema saihainaya obage ahase laiyawewaa")